# Is there a reverse operation for the vmsplice() system call in Linux?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, ipc

The `vmsplice` system call allows to implement zero-copy-send to a pipe from a set of user-level pages using the 'SPLICE_F_GIFT' flag. My question is whether there is a reverse operation, e.g., can I have a process at the other end of the pipe that does not simply `read()` or `aio_read()` the pipe, but instead does an operation that simply maps the piped data into its address space? This would in the end mean the transfer (move) of a memory mapping from the sender to the receiver process without any copying. Is this possible?

**Edit:** My use case looks as follows. I have two processes A and B. A generates data (>megabytes) and wants to pass it to B for further processing and then terminates. I'd like to avoid copying and just tell the kernel 'Look I have these pages here and don't need them anymore. Please attach them to B's address space and be done with it.'.

Simple shared-memory does not work for me, because the memory sent by A may be anywhere in its address space unless I restrict A to use a specific memory allocator that works on shared memory or temp files, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Are you looking for `mmap` of a pipe descriptor?

Comment: Not really. I'd like to send different mappings through the same pipe.

Comment: I'm not quite understand your case of use. Could you explain what and how you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question - is it clear now?

Comment: I think that you need some of the shared memory operations, nevertheless. It's most probably that you've seen the `shmget/shmat/shmdt` and others. Doesn't they are suitable for your purposes? Let's say that A process allocates a memory chunk and then attaches shared memory segment to that address and it's address space. Process B gets segment's ID from the pipe (for example) and do the same thing. Then B acks A that it has the ID and gets the segment attached so A can detach it. What do you think?..

Comment: As A and B may arbitrarily allocate memory objects using 'malloc', this would require me to tinker with their memory allocation policies (to make sure that their objects are allocated within shared memory).  This is theoretically possible, but I'd like to avoid this limitation.

Comment: even if we do the allocation from the shared memory we need to worry about losing pages when A or B crashes, in the vmsplice approach the kernel is aware of the pages and can cleanup accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are looking for `process_vm_readv` and `process_vm_writev`.

> These system calls transfer data between the address space of the
>   calling            process ("the local process") and the process
>   identified by pid ("the remote process").  The data moves directly
>   between the address spaces of the two processes, without passing
>   through kernel space.

See the man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

nope there is no reverse of vmsplice operation, there is a project going on now for putting DBUS in kernel you might want to take a look at it. I too have the same requirement and was investigating this whole vmsplice thing.

Comment: DBUS is not the questioner looks like, I think.